# Adding printer from printserver through different VLAN and subnet

Tags: networking, printing, printer

working on this issue for quite some time right now (about 2 weeks) but still cannot get it to work.

**my goal**

My goal is to have a printserver in one subnet A (192.168.200.0/24,  VLAN 20) and clients in another subnet B (192.168.0.0/24, VLAN 1). The printers are in subnet A and are connected via TCP/IP /raw) with a windows 10 PC that is sharing the printers. For testing purposes I've disabled the firewall on the printserver.
The printserver itself is not in a domain.

**Current status**

I can access the samba shares of the printserver and ping it. I can open shared folders and files and the printers are displayed. However when I try to add a printer I get the error: 0x00000709 or just an error that the printers cannot be added.

**What I've done**

I've set all the gpo-rules to enable anonymous access to the machine and enabled anyone to print on the shared printers.
Print sharing in network option is enabled an password usage disabled. The printserver is configured on a private network.
I've tried connecting to the printers from clients that are in a domain (AD) and with some that are not.

**networking**

I manage the network with an Ubiqiti USG-Pro and opened ports 443, 631, 137, 139 and 445 between the VLANs.

I'd appreciate any help.

**Edit:** I just wiresharked a client and the printserver and opened up all ports from VLAN 1 to VLAN 20 and from 20 to 1. I also tried a CUPS server on VLAN 20, but got the same error on my windows clients. After diggin more into error 0x00000709 i figured this might be a DNS issue. So right now I am setting up a local DNS-Server (BIND) in VLAN 20 (VLAN 20 is a device VLAN and accessible from all current and future VLANs). I'll comment or even post if this is a working solution.

Comment: If you're relying on Windows protocols for cross-subnet service browsing and name resolution when trying to add these printers, you're going to have a bad time unless everything is in the same AD domain and using the same WINS server. Can you add the printers by manually putting in the IP address of the print server (and I suppose also manually entering the appropriate print queue name for the printer you're adding)?

Comment: @Spiff Unforutantely I cannot add any printer by using the IP-address of the print server. I can only add the printers directly, without the print server. HEre ist a screento of the [error messages](https://imgur.com/a/ATOcXZx). I'll monitor the network traffic using wireshark on the printserver and a client now. I hop it's just a port issue. (I already tried CUPS and it didn't work. So it might not be Windows, but some network issue.)

Comment: I've not tried printer sharing like this in a while, but bear in mind that ever since last years 'PrintNightmare' patch, print sharing in windows has definitely taken a bad turn. It might be due do that.

Comment: @Silbee It seems like this is the main issue here. I now put the printserver the printers and 2 clients (1 in a domain and 1 in a workgroup) in the same network. I am still not able to add the printer as network printer. The workgroup client cannot even access the shared folders (anonymous session), while the domain client (guest session) can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to solve my issue with a windows 10 printserver. However I was able to solve it with CUPS. Here is my working setup:

## Network setup

### Network A:

192.168.0.0/24 VLAN 1 - has domain clients

### Network B:

192.168.200.0/24 VLAN 20 - has devices, like printers and the printserver, TVs, ...

**printserver:** 192.168.200.10 running an Ubuntu 20.04 server with CUPS

### Network C

192.168.10.0/22 VLAN 10 - has guest policy on the attached wifi (client separation)

### printports for firewall

- 631

### Firewall rules

- LAN IN A (any port) TO printserver (printports)
- LAN IN C (any port) TO printserver (printports)

## Adding a printer

Search for printers in windows and add a printer manually. Choose to add a printer with a network address and use `http://192.168.200.10:631/printers/<printername>`. Chose a generic printer driver (I use a PCL driver) and add the printer. This works in Network A, B and C. In network B windows even discovers the CUPS printer.
(I might have to fiddle with mDNS forwarding a bit more, but that's on another page.)